# Funtion pointer to function returning pointer to said function type

Tags: c, pointers

For an implementation of a finite state machine, I would like to achieve something like this:

```
currentFunction = currentFunction(int arg);
```

with `currentFunction` being a function pointer to a function that returns a function pointer of the same function type.

Is this possible in C? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the need to do really obscure things like this *always* originate from muddy program design. You are trying to solve problem X, and you think that method Y will do it. So you ask us how to get Y working, even though it was most likely not the correct solution to begin with. The root of the problem might be that X is incorrectly designed.

That being said, you can do this by using a struct as wrapper and thereby taking advantage of incomplete struct types:

```
typedef struct func_wrapper_t
{
  struct func_wrapper_t (*func) (int);
} func_t;

...

func_t some_function (int x)
{
  ...
  return (func_t){ some_function };
}

...

int main(void)
{
  func_t f = some_function(0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't flag the comment. Do you think it was automatically removed because it contained the word `Upvoted` ? Strange. Anyway, this is much better because you don't have to cast and can't make a mistake.

Comment: @2501 Not quite sure what you are talking about. I haven't flagged any comments.

Comment: A positive comment was removed.

Comment: @2501 Maybe it was a false positive? :P

Comment: That's pretty funny.

Answer (score 1):

Have the function return a pointer to a function and then cast it to the correct type:

```
typedef void( plain )( void );
typedef plain*( type )( int );

plain* Function2( int value );

plain* Function( int value )
{
    return ( plain* )&Function2 ;
}

int main( void )
{
    type* function = ( type* )Function( 55 ) ;
}
```

This is very error prone, so you should probably change your approach to the solution and not use this.

Comment: I think this is about as undefined as the `void*` solution. And for good reasons: I'm pretty sure this could would mess up the code that picks the appropriate calling convention on many systems.

Comment: @Lundin It is defined: *A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another
type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted
pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type,
the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: Yeah I am aware of that text. The thing is, the compiler expects a function of return type void and you give it a function pointer return type, or vice versa. So it seems likely that the types are not compatible indeed, in which case you invoke undefined behavior and the compiler generates an incorrect calling convention.

Comment: @user694733 No they are not. In practice, they most likely have the same representation (just a number like any pointer), but the _calling convention_ generated for the function call may differ depending on the function type. The actual function pointer copy/assignment is not the problem, calling the function is.

Comment: @Lundin I don't follow. A function pointer is converted to a function pointer of a different type and then back to the original type. This is defined in the Standard. If you're suggesting that an implementation doesn't follow that, then it isn't conforming.

Comment: @Lundin No, the function call is done with the type: `type`, as you can see in the assignment: `type* function = ( type* )Function( 55 ) ;`

Comment: Yeah nevermind that, I confused which type that was the return type.

Answer (score -2):

There's an ugly solution which relies on casting

```
typedef void* (*FunctionType)(int);
void* func(int a){
    return (void*)func;
}

int main(void){
    FunctionType p = (FunctionType)func(3);
}
```

Comment: Functor objects and operator overloading won't work well in C though.